# crispy_forms.exceptions.CrispyError: |as_crispy_field got passed an invalid or inexistent field - models.ForeignKey

Tags: python, html, django, django-crispy-forms

I'm trying to create a frontend data entry page for an existing model. However, when clicking the link, I get an error:

```
crispy_forms.exceptions.CrispyError: |as_crispy_field got passed an invalid or inexistent field
```

Just to be clear, adding the data from Django Admin works with no issues at all.

Having looked through a number of answered questions here, one did highlight what I believe could be problem, but it was out of context and did not provide much of an explanation.

I am trying to create a frontend entry form for users that corresponds with a foreign key.

**models.py**

```
class NewHandoff(models.Model):
    handoff_pk = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    handoff_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True,verbose_name="Handoff Date")
    shift1_pri = models.ForeignKey(Engineer,on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name="Shift 1 Primary")
    shift1_sec = models.ForeignKey(Engineer,on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name="Shift 1 Secondary")

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.handoff_date}"
    
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Handoffs'

# New Handoff Form
class NewHandoffForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = NewHandoff
        fields = ['shift1_pri','shift1_sec']
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
from django.views import View
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.http.response import HttpResponse
from django.contrib import messages
from .models import AttentionForm,  NewHandoffForm

# Handoff View Page
class NewHandoffView(LoginRequiredMixin,View):
    def get(self, request):
        greeting = {}
        greeting['heading'] = "New Handoff"
        greeting['pageview'] = "Handoff"
        return render (request,'handoff/handoff-new.html')

    def post(self, request):
        if request.method == "POST":
            if "add-new-handoff-button" in request.POST:
                create_new_handoff_form = NewHandoffForm(request.POST)
                create_new_handoff_form.save()
                return redirect("/handoff/handoff-create")
```

**handoff-new.html**

```
{% extends 'partials/base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% load humanize %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block extra_css %}
    <link href="{% static 'libs/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
{% endblock %}

{% block contents %}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <!-- New Form -->
                    <form method="POST">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="row-fluid pb-1">
                                <!-- Field 1 -->
                                <div class="mb-3">
                                    {{ form.shift1_pri|as_crispy_field }}
                                </div>
                                <!-- End of Field 1 -->
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="d-flex flex-wrap gap-2">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary waves-effect waves-light" name="add-new-handoff-button">Create New Handoff</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    <!-- End of New Form -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}

{% block extra_javascript %}
{% endblock %}
```

Someone mentioned in another post that forms should correlate with the declared form name `{{ form.shift1_mod|as_crispy_field }}` so it should actually be `{{ create_new_handoff_form.shift1_mod|as_crispy_field }}` but I have tried changing this and still get the same problem, plus, another model form works fine with just form despite the name of the form being attention_form.

Does anyone have any idea or can point me in the right direction? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not passing the form through the context in the template. As you are inheriting `View`, Add the following line in the get() and afterwards in the post() method appropriately:

```
form = NewHandoffForm()

# and then change return
return render(request,'handoff/handoff-new.html', {'form': form })
```

Also, you have a space after render in the get function. I hope this is a typo here, but not in your code.

Comment: I didn't follow this exact method above, but you were completely right! Can't believe how helpful everyone is on here! Thank you so much :)

Comment: Good to know that. The best thing about this platform is `Learn. Implement. Share. Repeat...`